# How to integrate Hibernate with Spring Boot.?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am facing issues while integrating hibernate with SpringBoot.

My HibernateUtil.java class,

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateUtil {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory factory;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Factory is not a hibernate factory.");
        }
        return factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }
}
```

My EmployeeDAO.java class.

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    public void save(Employee emp) {    
        Session session = null; 
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            System.out.println("Session got.");
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(emp);
            tx.commit();
        } catch(HibernateException he) {
            he.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After implementing this i am still getting this error,

Description:

Field sessionFactory in com.demo.dao.EmployeeDAO required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need not manually create a session Spring boot will automatically take care.

Create a interface

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, int> {
/* note int I am considering employee id will be integer or you can use required type in the second parameter as per primary key */
}
```

Autowire this EmployeeRepository  in your service class. you will be able to work with data layer.

You can read more in this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hibernate

Comment: I am aware of that. But my problem is i want to use Hibernate with SpringBoot.